# what does "JavaScript sanitization doesn't save you from innerHTML" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm learning xss prevention through this ppt:http://stash.github.io/empirejs-2014/#/2/23, and I have a question on this page.

It says "JavaScript sanitization doesn't save you from innerHTML", and I tried a simple test like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script>
    var userName = "Jeremy\x3Cscript\x3Ealert('boom')\x3C/script\x3E";
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "<span>"+userName+"</span>";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I opened this html on my browser(chrome), I only saw the name "Jeremy",by using F12, I saw

```html
<div id="test"><span>Jeremy<script>alert('boom')</script></span></div>
```

Although the script had been added to html, the alert box didn't come out.

"JavaScript sanitization doesn't save you from innerHTML" I think this means that the word "boom" should be alerted. Am I right?

Comment: "*Am I right?*". No. *innerHTML* doesn't execute scripts.

Comment: innerHTML *can* be made to execute script through the use of inline attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations), `innerHTML` prevents `<script>` elements from executing directly<sup>1</sup>, which means your test should not alert anything. However, it does not prevent event handlers from firing later on, which makes the following possible:

```js
var name = "\x3Cimg src=x onerror=alert(1)\x3E";
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

<sup>(script adapted from the example in the article, with escape sequences although I'm not sure those are relevant outside of `<script>` elements)</sup>

Since `<script>` elements never execute when inserted via `innerHTML`, it's not clear to me what that slide is trying to convey with that example.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is actually specified in HTML5. MDN links to a 2008 draft; in the current W3C Recommendation, it's located near the end of section 4.11.1, [just before section 4.11.1.1 begins](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#dom-script-text):

> **Note:** When inserted using the `document.write()` method, `script` elements execute (typically synchronously), but when inserted using `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` attributes, they do not execute at all.